# ViewPager2 not honoring Constraints Layout

Tags: android-studio, android-constraintlayout, android-viewpager2

I want to have an activity with an image, and below the image a viewpager2, that will change based on click of the users. So then I come up with this layout for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic_imageView"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"/>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_pic_imageView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But, it's on top of the imageview... what do I need to change? I tried match_parent, and 0dp but it's always on top of the image view

Answer (score 2):

> You need to give ViewPager bottom constraint and as we gave top and bottom constraint we can give height 0dp.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic_imageView"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_pic_imageView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```